# Problemas con el toast en android studio

Tags: android, checkbox, android-toast

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña app que me mostrará un Toast cuando de clic a un botón.

El problema es que me ejecuta la app normal pero no me muestra el toast y tampoco me lanza error, es como si no lo hubiera puesto. Agradecería la ayuda de alguien gracias.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox c1;
    CheckBox c2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        c1=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.idcheck1);
        c2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.idcheck2);

    }

    public void  onClick(View view){
        if(view.getId()==R.id.btn1){
            validar();
        }
    }


    private void validar(){
        String cad="Seleccionado:\n";
        if (c1.isChecked()==true){
            cad+="Opcion 1";
        }
        if(c2.isChecked()==true){
            cad+="Opcion 2";
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cad , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: En principio simplemente ocurre que no has indicado a quién tiene que "atender" ese evento onclick, por lo tanto no se procesa "validar" y tu Toast no se muestra. échale un vistazo a este enlace sobre cómo atender el evento de click en un chec https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149414/how-to-receive-a-event-on-android-checkbox-check-change

Comment: Daniel, para esto tu Activity debe implementar el listener: View.OnClickListener , de otra forma define el listener directamente al botón. Además el método debe ser onClick() no onclick().

Comment: que es btn1?  ...

Answer (score 1):

**No se llama el método `onClick()` porque no estas definiendo el listener a tu Activity,**

```
   public void  onClick(View view){
        if(view.getId()==R.id.btn1){
            validar();
        }
    }
```

**para que se mande llamar este método, tu clase Activity debe implementar `View.OnClickListener`** de esta forma:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
```

de esta forma puedes definir el listener a el elemento que llamaría el clic:

```
 Button boton = findViewById(R.id.btn1); 
 //Define listener.
 boton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

y llamaría el método

```
 onclick()
```

Este sería el código completo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

    CheckBox c1;
    CheckBox c2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        c1=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.idcheck1);
        c2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.idcheck2);

        Button boton = findViewById(R.id.btn1); 
        //Define listener.
        boton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void  onClick(View view){
        if(view.getId()==R.id.btn1){
            validar();
        }
    }


    private void validar(){
        String cad="Seleccionado:\n";
        if (c1.isChecked()==true){
            cad+="Opcion 1";
        }
        if(c2.isChecked()==true){
            cad+="Opcion 2";
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cad , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

---

**Si no deseas que tu clase `Activity` implemente el listener `View.OnClickListener` simplemente define el listener a la vista**:

```
 Button boton = findViewById(R.id.btn1); 
 boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                 validar();

                }
            });
```